# ng2-page-scroll: Wait for content to load when working across routes

Tags: angular

I use ng2-page-scroll (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-page-scroll) like this:

`<a pageScroll [routerLink]="['router-one']" href="#content1">Link 1</a>
<a pageScroll [routerLink]="['router-two']" href="#content2">Link 2</a>
<a pageScroll [routerLink]="['router-three']" href="#content3">Link 3</a>`

Works fine, except that... let's say I'm on `router-one`, fragment `content1`, and I click `Link2`, where I have many components, that need to load their data.

After routing has finished, its just goes to my fragment, which is understandable, but my data is probably not loaded yet, and will load in the next 1000ms maybe.

So it basically, goes to that id/fragment, and than the data loads, and you are no longer seeing on your screen the section with the id/fragment that you requested for.

How can I set like a delay to give the data a chance to load, when you work across routes?

**EDIT:**

```
const childRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'router-one', component: OneComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'router-two', component: TwoComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'router-three', component: ThreeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

Comment: Can you post some more code?

Comment: You should create [Resolver](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html)

Comment: @Chrillewoodz, that's basically it, no more code... :) I installed the module following the steps from the link.

Comment: Well you must have a router, no?

Comment: @Chrillewoodz , well yeah, i edited my post. As a mention, the module seems to work, but it just scrolls before the data is loaded, so after the data is loaded the section is not on fold anymore, must scroll down to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The  problem is that the data on the route you navigate to requires some time to load?
I guess the best way to handle this situation is using the PageScrollService on the target route/component to trigger the scroll animation as soon as the data is loaded (you probably get an event when this happens, e.g. the http request finished). You may pass the scroll target element to the new route as optional route parameter. (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters)

```
<a [routerLink]="['router-one', { scrollTo: '#content1' }]">Link 1</a>
```

In your target component you then access the scrollTo value from the activatedRoute and pass it into PageScrollService, something like:

```
constructor(
 private route: ActivatedRoute,
 private pageScrollService: PageScrollService,
 @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        if (params['scrollTo']){
            let pageScrollInstance: PageScrollInstance = PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, params['scrollTo']);
            this.pageScrollService.start(pageScrollInstance);
        }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/Nolanus/ng2-page-scroll/issues/48#issuecomment-254177855

Answer (score 2):

It's easy for the target fragment to be in a different place from when the view loads to after the view has been hydrated.  In my case the target ID wasn't even present until the data had loaded.  Solved this by grabbing a copy of the fragment and using ng2-page-scroll to scroll to the fragment AFTER data loads.

Page has target id:

```
<span id="target-position"></span>
```

Link specifies fragment separately from the route:

```
<a [routerLink]="['some-route']" fragment="target-position">Link 1</a>
```

Partial component code:

```
routeFragment: string;

ngOnInit() {

  this.route.fragment.subscribe(f => {
    // save fragment for later scroll target
    this.routeFragment = f;
  });

  this.someDataService.get().subscribe(data => {

    // do something with data
    this.data = data;

    // data is loaded, scroll to original fragment
    this.pageScrollService.start(PageScrollInstance.simpleInstance(this.document, `#${this.routeFragment}`));

  });

}
```